# Can't see the Fields I'm trying to add in pyQgis?

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes

On Qgis 2.14.11 I successfully made buffered envelopes from my "roads" Qgsvectorlayer, and they load fine on the screen.

I am now trying to feed a QgsFields object to a vector layer shapefile and I don't see that reflected in the data table.

Nor have I been able to copy the attributes from every feature in "Roads" to each new feature I put into "layers"

I suspect that my code is lacking...

```
 from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
    import os  

working_dir = '/example'
os.chdir(working_dir)
project = QgsProject.instance()

roads = iface.addVectorLayer("/example/ALL_zones_updated_dissolved.shp", "ZDOT_Roads", "ogr")
if not roads:
    print("Layer failed to load!")

temp_path = 'temp'
os.chdir(temp_path)

fields = QgsFields(roads.fields()) 

crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4523, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.PostgisCrsId)
writer = QgsVectorFileWriter("multi_gon.shp", "utf-8", fields, QGis.WKBMultiPolygon, crs, "ESRI Shapefile")
if writer.hasError() != QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
    print "Error when creating shapefile: ",  w.errorMessage()

layer = iface.addVectorLayer("/examples/temp/multi_gon.shp", "Roadbounds", "ogr")
if not layer:
    print("Layer failed to load!")   

for feature in roads.getFeatures():

    inAttr   = feature.attributes()
    inFields = roads.fields() 
    inGeom = feature.geometry() 
    bf_inGeom = inGeom.buffer(500,1).boundingBox()
    gPolygon = QgsGeometry.fromRect(bf_inGeom)

    feat = QgsFeature()
    feat.setGeometry(gPolygon)
    feat.setFields(QgsFields(roads.fields()))
    feat.setAttributes(inAttr)
    layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([feat])
```

Comment: Try adding `layer.updateFields()` after your last line.